# Hacker Earth(Basic I/O Question) Play With Numbers [ subarry ]

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, sub-array

I have been trying to solve this problem and it works good with small numbers but not the big  10^9 numbers in Hacker Earth

You are given an array of n numbers and q queries. For each query you have to print the floor of the expected value(mean) of the subarray from L to R.

INPUT:

First line contains two integers N and Q denoting number of array elements and number of queries.

Next line contains N space separated integers denoting array elements.

Next Q lines contain two integers L and R(indices of the array).

OUTPUT:

print a single integer denoting the answer.

Constraints:

1<= N ,Q,L,R <= 10^6

1<= Array elements <= 10^9

NOTE

Use Fast I/O

````
using namespace std;
long int solvepb(int a, int b, long int *arr,int n){
    int result, count = 0;
    vector<long int>res;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i+1 >= a && i+1 <=b){
            res.push_back(arr[i]); 
            count += arr[i];
        }
    }
    result = count / res.size();
    return result;
}
int main(){
    int n,q;cin>>n>>q;
    long int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    while(q--){
        int a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        cout<<solvepb(a,b,arr,n)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

So currently, the issue with your algorithm is that each time you are computing the mean over two indices in the array. This means that if the queries are particularly bad, for each of the Q queries, you might iterate through all N elements of the array.
How can one try to reduce this? Notice that because sums are additive, the sum up to an index i is the same as the sum up to an index j plus the sum of the numbers between i and j. Let me rewrite that as an equation -

`sum[0:i] = sum[0:j] + sum[j+1:i]`

It should be obvious now that by rearranging this equation, you can quickly get the sum between two indices by storing the sum of numbers up to an index. (i.e. `sum[j+1:i] = sum[0:i] - sum[0:j]`). This means that rather than having O(N*Q), you can have O(N + Q) runtime complexity. The O(N) part of the new complexity is from iterating the array once to get all the sums. The O(Q) part comes from answering the Q queries.

This kind of approach is called prefix sums. There are some optimized data structures like Fenwick trees made specifically for prefix sums that you can read about online or on Wikipedia. But for your question, a simple array should work just fine.

A few comments about your code:

In your for loop in the solvepb function, you are going from 0 to n always, but you didn't need to. You could have specified to go from a to b if you knew a was smaller than b. Otherwise, you go from b to a.

You also do not really use the vector. The vector in the solvepb function stores array elements, but these are never used again. You only seem to use it to find the number of elements from a to b, but you can get that by simply subtracting the difference between the two indices (i.e. `b-a+1` if `a < b` otherwise `a-b+1`)